# How to make a variable empty if it will not find the item?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Lessons and have Test for the Lesson. I am looking for particular test, which exists for some lesson and doesn't exist for some Lessons.

- My Question is How to make variable test as empty array if it will not found the data?

```
$test = Test::where('level', 'medium')->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id)->firstOrFail();
```

I mean if the code above item doesn't exists, how i am gonna assign it as empty array, I am getting Error cause for some cases it is not finding the data, I tried to put code inside try and catch but didnt helped me!

Comment: Neither `firstOrFail()` nor `first()`, will return an array. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Can you show how you're using/testing the data i.e. where you're testing to see if it's empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firstOrFail` should throw an exception so in try catch you should be able to resolve it, another approach is the following:

```
$test = Test::where('level', 'medium')->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id)->first() ?? [];
```

the `??` operator means if the result of the first part is `null` it will return the empty array.

Answer (score 1):

`firstOrFail()` function return first found item, but if item doesn't exist, it throw exception `ModelNotFoundException`. I don't know why you want to put empty array here, but that is solution for your case:

```php
$test = Test::where('level', 'medium')
    ->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id)
    ->first(); // this returns null if item doesn't exist
$test = $test ?? []; // this turns null to empty array
```

Beter solution is to take `null` from query result and check it in if. Example:

```php
$test = Test::where('level', 'medium')
    ->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id)
    ->first();

if (!$test) {
    // do this, if item doesn't exist
}
```

or like that:

```php
try {
    $test = Test::where('level', 'medium')
        ->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id)
        ->firstOrFail();
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
    // do this, if item doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data from database or an empty array (collection) if there is no matching data,  you may use `get()` function on query builder.

```php
$test = Test::where('level', 'medium')
            ->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use exists() or doesntExist() to check if records exists or not.

```
$test = Test::where('level', 'medium')->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id)->exists();
```